# Angular checkbox, one should always stay checked

Tags: angular, typescript

In my case, I have 2 checkboxes 
Active and InActive, by default when page is loaded, both will be set to true, user can uncheck any of them, but both cannot be un-checked at the same time.

What I have tried to do is to use getter for getting value and method call when value is being updated and to check, if change is 'valid'

.ts code

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-actions-filter',
  templateUrl: './actions-filter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./actions-filter.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

export class ActionsFilterComponent implements OnInit {
  private _isActive: boolean = true;
  get isActive(): boolean {
    return this._isActive;
  }

  setActive(value: boolean) {
    if (this._isInActive === false && value === false) {
      this._isActive = true;
      return;
    }
    this._isActive = value;
  }`

  private _isInActive: boolean = true;
  get isInActive(): boolean {
    return this._isInActive;
  }

  setInActive(value: boolean) {
    if (this._isActive === false && value === false) {
      this._isInActive = true;
      return;
    }
    this._isInActive = value;
  }

  constructor() { }`

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

and my .html

```
<div class="app-filter-block">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <div class="checkbox btn">
      <input type="checkbox" id="btn-action-active" (change)='setActive($event.target.checked)' [checked]="isActive" />
      <label for="btn-action-active">Active</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox btn">
      <input type="checkbox" id="btn-action-inactive" (change)='setInActive($event.target.checked)'
        [checked]='isInActive' />
      <label for="btn-action-inactive">Inactive</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

update: Checkbox is being used from clarity 
https://clarity.design/documentation/button-group

Comment: in the setActive/setInActive functions you can pass in the $event and check if both are unchecked. It they are unchecked set the $event.target.checked as true. This should work

Comment: @Vinaayakh osom. ! Thank you very much, did not even thought about updating event not the value in class.

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply disable the other checkbox if this is unchecked.

```
<div class="app-filter-block">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <div class="checkbox btn">
      <input type="checkbox" id="btn-action-active" 
      (change)='setActive($event.target.checked)' 
      [disabled]="!isInActive"
      [checked]="isActive" />
      <label for="btn-action-active">Active</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox btn">
      <input type="checkbox" id="btn-action-inactive" 
      (change)='setInActive($event.target.checked)'
      [disabled]="!isActive"
      [checked]='isInActive' />
      <label for="btn-action-inactive">Inactive</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```